# Зачем нужны разные типы ссылок в Java?

Tags: java

Углубляю познания о джаве. Наткнулся на статью о типах ссылок. Понял, что существуют 4 типа ссылок:

1. Strong reference
2. Weak Reference
3. Soft Reference
4. Phantom Reference

Незнаю, правильно ли я понял, поэтому прошу подправить.

1 Тип сильная ссылка (***Strong reference***)

```
Object object = new Object();//создал обьект 
object = null;//теперь может быть собран сборщиком мусора
```

2 Тип слабая ссылка (***Weak Reference***)

```
// какой-то объект
Object object= new Object ();

// слабая ссылка на него
WeakReference<Object > weakStudent = new WeakReference<Object >(object);

// теперь объект Object  может быть собран сборщиком мусора
object= null;
```

3 Тип мягкая ссылка (**Soft Reference**)

```
// какой-то объект
Object object= new Object ();

// слабая ссылка на него
SoftReference<Object > softStudent = new SoftReference<Object >(object)

// теперь объект Student может быть собран сборщиком мусора
// но это случится только в случае сильной необходимости JVM в памяти
object= null;
```

4 Тип фантомная ссылка (ничего не понял про него)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Более-менее рассказано в [документации к пакету `java.lang.ref`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html):

> Soft references are for implementing memory-sensitive caches, weak references are for implementing canonicalizing mappings that do not prevent their keys (or values) from being reclaimed, and phantom references are for scheduling post-mortem cleanup actions. Post-mortem cleanup actions can be registered and managed by a [`Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html).

Подробнее и по-русски, в порядке убывания жёсткости:

- **Сильные**, они же обычные, нужны для указания на объекты, которые должны обязательно оставаться в памяти всё то время, что эти ссылки на него существуют. Если не складывается, получите `OutOfMemoryError`.
- **Мягкие** ссылки полезны для кэшей, чувствительных к доступному объёму оперативной памяти. Объекты по ним могут зачиститься, но только в случае необходимости. Например, если нужно насоздавать ещё объектов с сильными ссылками, а уже негде, лучше освободить кэш и замедлить работу, чем уронить процесс напрочь.
- **Слабые** ссылки полезны для сопоставления объектов чему-нибудь без удерживания их от зачистки когда они больше не нужны (а-ля `Map<Ключ, WeakRef<Значение>>`). На возможность зачистки они не влияют вообще никак, слабые ссылки будут очищены при очередном запуске сборщика.
- **Фантомные** ссылки возникают, когда объект уже признан мусором, финализирован и находится в процессе зачистки, о чём можно узнать с помощью [класса `Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) и выполнить в это время какие-то собственные действия.

Плюс общее правило: политика зачистки для некоего объекта и очистки ссылок на него определяется **самыми жёсткими** из всех ссылок, что на него указывают.

---

Глоссарий не вполне очевидных переводов:

- зачистить, зачистка — reclaim, reclamation
- очистить — clear